# Eventstore projections not storing in assigned stream

Tags: typescript, events, event-handling, projection, eventstoredb

I am running a projection on my *eventstoreDB* trying to create my project with *Event sourcing*. This is my projection, running with no errors:
(the project is made with node and ts)

```
 options({
      resultStreamName: "userData",
      $includeLinks: true,
      reorderEvents: false,
      processingLag: 500
    })
    
    fromStream('user')
    .when({
      $init: function() {
        return {
          cash: 0
        }
      },
      trans: function(state, event) {
        state.cash += event.body.cash;
      }
    })
    .transformBy(function(state) {
      state.cash = 10;
    })
    .outputState()
```

for some reason, it seems like the result won't be uploaded to the `resultstreamName` as specified.

I see that the projection ( called user), is run:

[image]

my projection "test" with cash info:

[image]

How can I make the result projection to be stored in the stream `userData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm no expert, so if this does not work please comment and I'll delete this answer.*

From information I could find, you do not need the `transformBy` call here. As you're not *transforming* the state into an output model, you should be able to perform the calculation directly in your `trans` event handler. You also need to return the state, after adding the cash amount, as follows:

```javascript
options({
    resultStreamName: "userData",
    $includeLinks: true,
    reorderEvents: false,
    processingLag: 500
})

fromStream('user')
    .when({
        $init: function() {
            return {
                cash: 0
            }
        },
        trans: function(state, event) {
            state.cash += event.body.cash; // (maybe event.data.cash instead?)
            return state;
        }
    })
    .outputState()
```